# How to filter realm contacts by phone number with Predicate?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, predicate

I have a table view show all contacts use RealmSwift.
How to filter realm contacts by phone number with Predicate?

```
    class Contact: Object {
        @objc dynamic var firstName = ""
        @objc dynamic var lastName = ""
        var number = List<String>()
        @objc dynamic var avatar:Data?
       var email = List<String>()
    }

    var contacts:Results<Contact>?

    //When click search button
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.contacts = self.phoneContact.readContactFromLocal()
        var contacts_tmp1 = self.contacts
        if self.txt_search.text != nil && self.txt_search.text != ""{
              let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName contains[c] %@ OR lastName contains[c] %@", self.txt_search.text!, self.txt_search.text!)
               contacts_tmp1 = contacts_tmp1?.filter(predicate)
        }
        contacts_tmp1 = contacts_tmp1?.sorted(byKeyPath: "firstName", ascending: true)

        self.contacts = contacts_tmp1
        self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
```

Comment: Please provide us the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm filtering by firstName and lastName in Predicate

Comment: @LeVanPhuong Plz update your code in the question, not comment

Comment: I was updated code in the question. Thanks

Comment: It seems like you already know how to use `filter` and `NSPredicate`s to filter a Realm query, so what is your actual questions? Are you simply trying to retrieve the contact(s) whose `number` property matches a given `String`?

Comment: I can filter by firstName and lastName in Predicate because they are String. But number is List, I don't know how to filter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on a list of primitives is not supported in realm. You can only filter on lists of realm objects. [Issue tracking here.](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5334) There are some workarounds you can do, such as a manual comparison of strings, but there is no way to do it in realm.